# How do firebase cloud functions send messages to topics using the Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a cloud function that performs some logic and when it's done it sends a message to a topic called `onPlanBeginning`:

```js
export const onNewPendingPlan = functions.firestore
    .document('pendingPlanCreations/{id}')
    .onCreate(async (pendingPlanDocSnap) => {
        try {
            //[... some logic that executes correctly ...]

            console.log(`Sending to topic`) // this log appears correctly in the firebase console logs

            const messageResponse = await admin.messaging().sendToTopic('onPlanBeginning', {
                data: {
                    foo: 'bar',
                },
                notification: {},
            })

            console.log(`Message id: ${messageResponse.messageId}`) // this one too, with a message id
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
    })
```

And then, this function is supposed to log that message's content:

```js
export const onPlanBeginning = functions.pubsub
    .topic('onPlanBeginning')
    .onPublish(async (message) => {
        try {

            console.log(`Recieved message: ${JSON.stringify(message.json)}`)
            return

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
    })
```

The logs before and after the execution of `sendToTopic` appear correctly in the firebase console logs. But the message is not published in the topic and therefore the handler Cloud Function is not executed.

Am I missing something? I have manually published a message to the topic using the GCloud Console and the Cloud Function `onPlanBeginning` executed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first Cloud function is sending a message to a **Firebase Cloud Messaging** topic, while your second Cloud Function is listening to a **Google Cloud PubSub** topic. While both are called topic, they have nothing to do with each other and messages sent to an FCM topic are not delivered to a PubSub topic observer.

To send a message to a PubSub topic, have a look at this [example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/samples/publishMessage.js).

There is no way to receive an FCM message in Cloud Functions. FCM SDKs to receive messages are only available for iOS and Android.